# selenium unicode encode error

Tags: python, selenium

When retrieving the content of a google search result page I get this error?

```
print driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('innerHTML')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe6' in position 15663: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm calling the python script from PHP like this

```
exec('python selenium_scrape.py');
```

This solves the problem, but then all unicode chars will be encoded twice

```
print driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('innerHTML').encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Can you try to encode the the text `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('innerHTML').encode("utf-8")` ?

Comment: have tried that but then all utf8 chars will be encoded twice

Comment: I don't think so that encoded elements will be encoded twice. It should throw an exception if the encoding is done twice.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you're printing to a stdout that uses ASCII (7 bit) encoding. Call Python with a locale setting that uses utf-8, or do some appropriate encoding of the (unicode) HTML content to a 7-bit character string first.

Comment: how to call the python script with utf8?

Comment: Have updated my question.. I'm calling the script from PHP

Comment: If you have the locale (or one better suited to your language) available on your machine, you could call at the shell prompt: `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 python script.py` (update: don't know about PHP, though)

Comment: If I do this `print driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('innerHTML').encode('utf-8')` I don't get the error.. but then all unicode chars will be encoded twice

Comment: UTF-8 isn't a 7-bit encoding (it's called UTF-8 for a reason). Your output accepts only 7 bit, so Python will try to re-encode your UTF-8 string, by default using ASCII, which in turn is not capable of that. You'll have to either use some 7-bit Unicode codec or replace the characters beyond 7 bit, for example by their HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode the the text before printing:

```
print driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').get_attribute('innerHTML').encode("utf-‌​8")
```